# Parse iOS add user to an existing Role

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I'm trying to add a User to existing Parse.com role with a successful sign up.

```
//User has successfully signed up now that I have a cached currentUser we proceed to add them to the 'Moderator' Role:
 PFQuery *roleQuery = [PFRole query];
 [roleQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo:@"Moderator"];
 [roleQuery getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
      PFRole *role = (PFRole *)object;
      [role.users addObject:[PFUser currentUser]];
      [role saveInBackground];
    }
 }];
```

however, once their account processes I get this error:

```
[Error]: object not found for update (Code: 101, Version: 1.7.5)
```

Moderator, is an active Role in the backend. Can someone please help me overcome this hurdle and lead me in the right direction. This is aggravating. nothing is documented in the Parse iOS Guide for querying/adding users to existing roles.

Comment: I just tried your code, and it worked without a hitch, I'm not sure what you are doing wrong, but I'm still looking, it's strange that this is not working

Comment: Actually, what are the ACLs for the moderator role? list those real quick

Comment: Rookie mistake I supose @Larcerax it's not set to write for public access. Good catch